# GitLab do not run CI/CD pipeline when creating new merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My GitLab CI/CD is run when I:

- click `Create merge request`
- every commit in created branch
- when merge request branch is merged to master

I would like to skip first pipeline (on creating merge request), because I would like to optimize (fasten) my CI/CD.
On creating merge request new branch is created from master which already build successfully. There is no point of running the pipeline again.

Can I do that? I already check documentation for `when` but no idea how to solve this.

Comment: I'm also hoping to stop that superfluous build. I'm trying out the `only` keyword.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be possible at the moment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223698

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I often use the option `Create branch` instead of `Create merge request`. This can only be done in the issue view.
Then the first pipeline in this branch is running after the first push into the branch. With a push in the branch you can create a merge request.

[image: Create branch in issue view]

Comment: I don't understand how this could solve the issue. After creating a merge request your way, it will still start a new pipeline, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

In your `gitlab-ci.yml` file try setting the following workflow:

```
 workflow:
      rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
        when: never
      - when: always
```

This will check if the pipeline was triggered by a merge request and will prevent it from running. For all other cases, it allows the pipeline to run.