# ".gitlab-ci.yml" rule to do not run a pipeline on merge request creation

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

### Important note before going further:

The question [GitLab do not run CI/CD pipeline when creating new merge request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706129/gitlab-do-not-run-ci-cd-pipeline-when-creating-new-merge-request) is **not** a duplicate:
I am asking about ".gitlab-ci.yml" rules, but that question has no answers about this.

### Current GitLab (default) behavior

On an issue page I click "Create Merge Request" --> A new pipeline is started automatically.

### Required behavior

Do not run a pipeline on merge request creation

### My current ".gitlab-ci.yml"

```yaml
.default_rules:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: manual
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - "**/*.{py,c,cpp}"
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
        - poetry.lock
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      changes:
        - "**/*.{py,c,cpp}"
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
        - poetry.lock
    - if: $PIPELINE_TYPE == "multi-project-pipeline"
```

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION**
Do not run a job on Merge Request creation:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

your_job_name:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
```

**A LITTLE USEFUL BONUS**
Full rules to avoid duplicate pipelines (just in case if someone needs this):

```yaml
  rules:
    # Prevent creating duplicate pipelines because pipelines are already created for PUSH events.
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    # Do not run after Merge Request closing.
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: never
    # Do not run on Merge Request creation.
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
    # When to run:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      changes:
        # If the code has changed
        - "**/*.py"
```